# How to LOCK Virtual Studio Code Editor layout

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any option/extension/mod idea to **lock the layout of planes in VS code, especially the width of the leftmost group**.

The reason is there is no real support for 2 monitors, so I wrote a shell script which maximizes VS Code in a way that it covers 150% of one screen (starting at 50% of the left screen width)
So I have half the left screen for VS code, where I always want to keep one editor, and on the right, variable space for a second script/terminal/etc.

I like the 150% solution, as it just gives me so much more space. But having to readjust the width constantly is tedious.

If one is interested, here the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Function to extract the total workspace Y resolution (height) from the xrandr output
get_screen_y() {
  xrandr | awk '/Screen 0:/ {gsub(/,/, ""); print $10}' | cut -d 'x' -f 2
}

# Function to extract the total workspace X resolution (width) from the xrandr output
get_screen_x() {
  xrandr | awk '/Screen 0:/ {print $8}' | cut -d 'x' -f 1
}

# Function to extract the Y offset from the xrandr output
# this is the offset of the upper scrrens relative to the lower one
get_y_offset() {
  xrandr | awk '/eDP-1-1 connected primary/ {split($4, coords, "+"); print coords[3]}'
}

# Function to get the top bar height for the Visual Studio Code window
get_vscode_top_bar_height() {
  # Get the window ID of Visual Studio Code
  WINDOW_ID=$(xdotool search --name "Visual Studio Code")

  # Use xwininfo to get information about the window and extract the top bar height
  xwininfo -id "$WINDOW_ID" | awk '/Absolute upper-left Y:/ {print $4}'
}

# Get the window ID of Visual Studio Code
WINDOW_ID=$(xdotool search --name "Visual Studio Code")

# Calculate the dimensions for the VS Code window
SCREEN_WIDTH=$(get_screen_x)
SCREEN_HEIGHT=$(get_screen_y)
Y_OFFSET=$(get_y_offset)

xdotool windowmove $WINDOW_ID 1920 1
sleep 0.1

# Calculate the desired dimensions for the VS Code window
TOP_BAR_HEIGHT=$(get_vscode_top_bar_height)
# might be buggy, the use TOP_BAR_HEIGHT=74
DESIRED_WIDTH=$((SCREEN_WIDTH * 3 / 4))
DESIRED_HEIGHT=$((Y_OFFSET))
DESIRED_X=$((SCREEN_WIDTH / 4))
DESIRED_HEIGHT=$((DESIRED_HEIGHT - TOP_BAR_HEIGHT))

echo "Screen width: $SCREEN_WIDTH"
echo "Screen height: $SCREEN_HEIGHT"
echo "Y Offset: $Y_OFFSET"
echo "Top bar height: $TOP_BAR_HEIGHT"
echo "Desired X: $DESIRED_X"
echo "Desired width: $DESIRED_WIDTH"
echo "Desired height: $DESIRED_HEIGHT"

# Calculate the dimensions for the VS Code window

xdotool windowsize $WINDOW_ID $DESIRED_WIDTH $DESIRED_HEIGHT
sleep 0.1
xdotool windowmove $WINDOW_ID $DESIRED_X 0
```

Comment: you want to know how to set the width to a specific value and then lock it there? or just how to lock it?

Comment: you probably want to give this a thumbs up: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10121

Comment: I want to lock the width of a tab to not make it auto-resize when I open sth else.
I know this GitHub issue exists. It exists since 2016. VS Code is not going to get multi-monitor support any time soon.